# Search Request to Apache Solr other than browser

Tags: solr

I am making a search query on local Apache Solr Server by browser and see the results.

I want to make Same Query on the production server.

Since tomcat port is blocked on production, I cannot test the query results on the browser.

Is there any method to make query and see the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solr is a java web application: if you can't access the port it's listening to, you can't access Solr itself. There's no other way to retrieve data from a remote location. Usually on production Solr is put behind an apache proxy, so that it protects the whole Solr and makes accessible only the needed contexts, in your case `solr/select` for example to make queries.